# Why is ifstream returning the last value of input files twice?

Tags: c++, ifstream

Why is ifstream returning the last value of strings twice?

in

```
size_t c;
    while (1){
        myfile >> c;
        cells.push_back(c);
        if (myfile.eof()) break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) cout << cells[i] << endl;
```

with the input

```
    2   3
    9   7   11
    12  5   6
    3   4
```

cells[7] = cells[8] = 4

I've done this with a few similarly formatted inputs and it does this for all of them.

Comment: [Because youre using while!(myfile.eof())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to do this is

```
while (myfile >> c){

}
```

This completely eliminates your problem, as the eof() is not reached when the last value is read, but when the stream fails to read, so after that fail you do another push_back. The advantage of the above while construct is that it will break immediately on fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the result of an I/O operation before you use the data it returns.

In this case, that means your check on `eof()` should precede the `push_back()` call. To make the code safer you should also add a check for `fail()` on the stream, since the stream can fail for other reasons than reaching EOF.